# SQL Connection using .ini

Tags: c#, sql-server

guys i'm still new on developing system and I've encountered this

This is the string i use to connect. It is inside of a class.

```
 public string connections1 = "user id=sa;" +
                              "password=;server=SEAN\\SQLEXPRESS;" +
                              "Trusted_Connection= false;" +
                              "database= METROEXPRESS; ";
```

How do i change this to put the connection information in an `.ini` file?

Comment: So... are you asking how to parse the INI format?

Comment: i really don't know what term is it. But its like i would make an .ini file which will hold the parameters that will be use to connect to the database

Comment: I think you need to read up on a basic programming in C# book. You put the connection string in a file with a ini extension and read the ini files contents.

Comment: Why are you using a .INI file why not store the value of the connection string in a .Config file..?

Comment: If you have the choice, use something like Settings, not an INI file. INIs are a kinda inflexible way to store settings, and parsing isn't built-in.

Comment: Jesun use a .config file why are you trying to do things in .NET the way things use to be done in legacy platforms.. this is possible but its

Comment: actually that's what my boss told me. but what would be better?..configfile or .ini...can you explain the advantages and disadvantage of both of it..

Comment: OMG Jesun how about doing a google search and seeing why it's better to use a .config file vs a .INI file. does your boss understand .NET framework..? if not perhaps he should not be your boss..

Comment: ^ here is a bunch of [free books](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194812/list-of-freely-available-programming-books) good luck!

Comment: iv'e tried googling this kind of stuffs..but i really dont get it...i got zero knowledge with this .ini and configfile...can anybody enlighten me with this stuff... please...dont be harsh on me.. :D thanks..

Comment: if you can't understand it ..then how is it that you are programming..? just curious..? look at this link if you can't understand it ..then I am not sure you will understand the other answers that individuals post here.. that's not `harsh` that's reality http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2475811/app-config-vs-ini-files

Comment: yeah i know its reality, but in reality when you learn on how to use a certain thing you should know first how it work in order to know it.  we learn from the basic.

Comment: actually there is another school of thought.. you learn by example meaning you try some of the many examples that are out there and try to understand why or why not you do something.. I learned by just jumping in and I swam vs sinking

Comment: @DJKRAZE Everyone has to start somewhere, and just because you learn by trying doesn't mean everyone does.  I often start by reading a book on the subject matter.  Please relax.

Comment: I am totally relaxed Andy..I am just stating my opinion

Comment: well yeah...thanks everyone...i finally got where to start bout this .ini and config file... :D...

Comment: @DJKRAZE You're not coming off that way; it's coming off as abusive and abrasive.

Comment: Andy that's your opinion but thanks for pointing that out..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd not using an .ini file; you'd use a .config file, which is an XML file containing your configuration.  If you're doing a rich client app (console, winforms, wpf) add an Application Configuration to your project and go from there (look up the  section).  If you're doing an asp.net application, you should already have a web.config, which you can also add a  section to.

Here's an example: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/9a8c9f5a-092e-4c4a-87bb-9f35d8f55da1/

Answer (score 0):

.NET and C# don't have built-in mechanism to edit *.ini files. The standard format for configuration files in .NET is XML.

Check the next question if you still want to use *.ini files.
[Reading/writing an INI file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217902/reading-writing-ini-file-in-c-sharp)